# Cmmunication between server and mobile app

Tags: android

Can I recognise server communication to my app without intiating or sending any request from my mobile app? Could anyone tell me any possibilities or ideas related to this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Pratheeja

Comment: I'm curious to know how you do this for Android.  For iPhone it's a bit of a process to set up server-to-phone push- you have to get some X.509 certs working, which is always very simple and fun.

Comment: you mean any webserver?
if its...I think there's no way to communicate with server without send any request from client side

Comment: yes. Actually, my data which is to be used in my app will be in server. Once those data is updated at server side, I need to inform mobile app saying that data has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good starting point may be searching for push based methods [for iphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) and [for android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Cloud_to_Device_Messaging_Service)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will check it and come back.